# Как импортировать класс в проект?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне импротировать этот архив в проект?(я хочу объявить экземпляр этого класса).

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Я не знаю как импортировать  в код этот класс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляешь свой jar кнопкой <kbd>Добавить jar/папку</kbd> в нужный проект, потом импортируешь в коде нужный класс.

Comment: У  меня там уже добавлено, я же специально скрин выложил.Я как раз не знаю как импортировать.